# Varnish cache objects for as long as possible

Tags: varnish

According to the book, [Varnish automatically invalidates expired objects](https://book.varnish-software.com/4.0/chapters/Cache_Invalidation.html). By *invalidates*, I understand that it *removes* these objects from the data store, as soon as they're expired.

**Is there a way to instruct Varnish to keep these expired objects forever, to only invalidate the oldest ones when a new object needs to be stored?**

Keeping expired objects is important because they can still be revalidated on the origin server, that can return a `304` response if they are still valid (thus avoiding a new transfer).

I read about the [grace mode](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/handling_misbehaving_servers.html#grace-mode) that allows to keep objects beyond their TTL:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
  set beresp.grace = 30m;
}
```

**If I set the grace mode to something like 1 year, will it work as I want?**

- will it revalidate the expired objects with the origin server?
- will it automatically delete the oldest object when it needs to make room for a new one?

Comment: which version of varnish are you running?

Comment: Let's say the latest. Just considering Varnish for now.

Comment: Then I think a huge grace time tackles your issue. What it means is : If a request hits varnish during an object grace time and the object is still stored in varnish, then the object is returned to the client and then it is refresh with an "If Modified Since" request to the backend, renewing the cache.

Comment: Actually I don't want it to return a stale object, I want Varnish to query the backend server in real time, and only reply to the client once it got the `304` or `200` response from the backend.

Comment: In other words, you want varnish to store an object beyond it's ttl just to revalidate them using a IMS request saving you some bandwith between backend and varnish. Is that it ? If so, then I don't know how you can achieve that. During its ttl, the object will not be revalidated by Varnish, and after it is expired the grace time will let you serve it but it will be revalidated asynchronously.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that the behaviour I'm after is not the default, though: why evict an object from the cache as soon as it's expired, when you can revalidate it later on? As long as you've got space left in the storage, this can only be beneficial.

Comment: It's not physically evicted. Purging an object is resource consuming. It's just marked as staled (or banned). One cause, I could think about is when varnish revalidate an object against the backend it needs to be sure that the object is still stored in its cache. That's true during its ttl and grace time, but that's not 100% sure afterwards

Comment: It'd be cheaper to check whether the object is stored in the cache, than going straight to the origin server, though?

Answer (score 1):

Summary from what have been told in the comments :

```
If I set the grace mode to something like 1 year, will it work as I want?
will it revalidate the expired objects with the origin server?
```

Not quite. It will revalidate the expired objects but asynchronously. When a requests hits varnish and the object is expired but in its grace time, the stale object is immediatly returned and the object is then refreshed using an "If Modified Since" request to the backend. That seems to be what you want, except for serving a stale object.

```
will it automatically delete the oldest object when it needs to make room for a new one?
```

Varnish purges objects when it needs space, but even if the object is still stored somewhere, if it is expired then it won't be served to the client (unless if in grace mode)

```
Is there a way to instruct Varnish to keep these expired objects forever, to only invalidate the oldest ones when a new object needs to be stored?
```

I don't think there is a way to let Varnish keep a stale object other than the grace period.

I checked my varnish production (v4.1) logs and I only see IMS backend requests in case of `bgfetch` (async refresh during grace time) and `pass`. Whenever Varnish `MISS` the object in cache, the fetch was done without the IMS headers.

Answer (score 0):

are you actively invalidating your cached objects via `ban`? Than a grace of one year is what you are looking for ;).

Greetings,

Bastian

Comment: I don't want to invalidate anything via `ban`, all the objects must be cached according to their Cache-Control directive, but I want them to be kept after their max-age has been reached, to be revalidated and be reused if `304`.